# How to get summary for first searches link for wikipedia api?

Tags: python, wikipedia-api

I searched "python" on wikipedia api but it's getting too many links for that keyword.

Code I used:

```
import wikipedia

result = wikipedia.summary("python", sentences=3)
```

[image]

That is getting too many results but I want summary for first sub result.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the module and get the same error. You have to install another module known as Wikipedia API(https://pypi.org/project/Wikipedia-API/) by:-

> pip install Wikipedia-API

The code that worked for me is

```
>>> import wikipediaapi
>>> wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')
>>> page_py = wiki_wiki.page('python')
>>> print("Summary: %s" % page_py.summary[0:60])
```

Another thing you thought could be to get the list of queries related to the term "python". So complete code would be:-

```
import wikipedia
import warnings
import wikipediaapi
wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
try:
  page = wikipedia.page("python")
except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
  queries='\n'.join(str(e).split('\n')[1:])
queries=queries.split('\n')
page_py = wiki_wiki.page(queries[0])
print("Summary: %s..." % page_py.summary[0:80])
```

Hope this help. If you have any doubt then feel free to ask!